# How often should i run requirements.txt file in my python project?

Tags: python, pycharm, requirements.txt

Working on a python project and using pycharm . Have installed all the packages using requirements.txt. Is it a good practice to  run it in the beginning of every sprint or how often should i run the requirements.txt file ?

Comment: Running a text file doesn't make sense. What are you actually asking about?

Comment: to update or install new packages , should i run requirements.txt every time or should i let pycharm install it silently on the background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when the file changes, either because someone added more dependencies, or updated a library version.

As a recommendation, there are several ways to handle the requirements.txt so you don't have to edit it by hand to update new versions, like:

https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools

https://github.com/suutari/prequ

https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs

Comment: Thanks for listing down the links so that i can form my own opinion on this matter.Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO.

Let's say you're working on your project, already installed all the packages in the requirements.txt into your virtual environment, etc etc, at this point your environment is already setup.

Keep working on the project and installed a new package with pip or whatever, now your environment is ok but you're requirements.txt is not up to date, you need to update it adding the new package, but you don't need to reinstall all the packages in it every time this happens.

You only runs pip install -r requirements.txt when you want to run your project on a different virtual environment

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thought process and your understanding on this matter. Appreciate it a lot.